# Unity 3D object with Rigidbody sliding

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a cube with **Rigidbody** attached to it would slide slightly whenever I pressed the play button. If I leave it for awhile, it would slide to other side of the screen.

Anyone know how to solve this problem without using the "freeze position"? I don't know what I messed up in my project...

This is what the object looks like: 
[image]

Note: I need to use the gravity.

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Heh!  The solution here is:

## You had a rigidbody on the floor  :)

You don't do that  :)  Never.

---

If the "floor" surface **is flat**, then,

it **will not slide**.

You've got something strange going on, such as

- "floor" is NOT flat
- a feature like "Wind" turned on
- perhaps other objects invisible in the scene you have forgotten about are nudging it

PhysX does not have a "mind of it's own".  There is some simple reason it is moving.

---

Let's say the "floor" is indeed on an angle, so it SHOULD move, but you WANT it to NOT move.

What you obviously do:

Just as in the real world, **put something there to stop it moving**.

A small invisible wall will do the trick.  That's PhysX!

Comment: the floor position is X0, Y1, Z0, rotation is X0, Y0, Z0. But when it try to tilt the floor, changing its rotation of Z from 0 to 3, the cube moves uphill (positive X, positive Z) but slower... When i change the rotation Z to 4, the cube moves on positive Z...

Comment: Done ;) Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 2):

Usually rigidbody sliding happens when a lower rigidbody has lower mass than a higher rigidbody (forcing down the lower rigidbody). Typical problem with player having say mass 80 jumping on a cube with mass 1. In this case the collision is so violent that the cube will probably fly out (not only slide). 
The situation is very similar to the real world. Try to stay on a box of milk if you have 120 kg (ok, ok, 80 :) ).
When you try to eliminate this behavior, you need either increase the mass of the lower object or decrease the mass of the higher one or set the lower rigidbody to kinematic.

Answer (score 0):

The solutions above is not proper way of solving the problem. Unity has more features of physics than mass. If you get sliding on movement or because of other objects you should add proper drag value on your rigidbody. For example , lets say you have blocks spawning over top of other blocks and this creates horizontal sliding. In my case I add drag of 1 to the objects which has mass of ~ 1 kg. It depends on the scene and you should try different values on your case. Do not use bigger values and angular drag if it is not important.